# Putting formula into excel sheet using openpyxl in python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

A while back I got some help with putting formulas into a spreadsheet using xlsxwriter with this:
[Adding formulas to excel spreadsheet using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915308/adding-formulas-to-excel-spreadsheet-using-python/62918473?noredirect=1#comment111302883_62918473)

I needed to move to use openpyxl and am having a problem doing the same and filling in a column while incrementing the row.
If I try:

```
for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws3['AC2:AC'+str(ws3.max_row)],2):
    cellObj[0].value = "=VLOOKUP(B${0},'SheetName'!$B$2:$R$2199,17,FALSE)".format(i)
```

when I run the formulas are not showing in the Excel file.

I tried the example given earlier with the same result, no formula is entered into the sheet.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testy.xlsx')
Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet.columns[1], 1):
    cellObj.value = '=IF($A${0}=$B${0}, "Match", "Mismatch")'.format(i)
wb.save('testy.xlsx')
```

Any pointer/s would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, though excel gave a circular reference warning when I opened the document. Note that I had to set the sheet name to Sheet1 in the formula.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

print("\nAll Sheets:", wb.sheetnames, end='\n\n')

Sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for i, cellObj in enumerate(list(Sheet.columns)[1], 1):
    f = "=VLOOKUP(B${0},'Sheet1'!$B$2:$R$2199,17,FALSE)".format(i)
    print(f)
    cellObj.value = f
wb.save('testy.xlsx')
```

Comment: If I have an existing spreadsheet  named as in the above example and run I get the error:
`tryr.py
tryr.py:3: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
  Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tryr.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i, cellObj in enumerate(list(Sheet.columns)[1], 1):
IndexError: list index out of range`

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: If I modify the line 3 to Sheet = wb.sheetnames('Sheet1') and re-run I get the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tryr.py", line 3, in <module>
    Sheet = wb.sheetnames('Sheet1')
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`


Process finished with exit code 1